# @media syntax / possible combinations

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've seen some of these...:

```
@media print { ... }
@media screen, handheld, print, projection { ... }
@media all { ... }
@media all and (property:value) { ... }
@media screen and (property:value) { ... }
@media only screen and (property:value) { ... }
@media screen and (property:value) and (property:value) { ... }
@media screen and (property:value), tv and (property:value) { ... }
```

...but I'd like to know the exact syntax / all possible combinations for media queries because I'm modifying a CSS parser.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Have you been over to W3C and taken a look at the documentation?

Comment: Googled but didn't find anything specific to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link out: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

It looks like it has the possible options that you are looking for.

Comment: It doesn't explain the word "only" from the question above.

Comment: To be fair, Media Queries wasn't a recommendation yet back in 2010. Although, at the very least, it was a candidate recommendation, ready for implementation and general usage...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the latest W3C recommendation on media queries:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/