# @media, -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: - incorrect syntax for css rule

Tags: syntax, webkit, screen, media

Does anyone know what is wrong with this rule?

**@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
     #nav-main li.c_course div{margin-left:1px !important;}**

```
#nav-main li.c_course div{margin-left:1px !important;| margin-right:0px !important;;}
#nav-main li.c_course div div{margin-left:0px !important;}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #nav-main li.c_course div{margin-left:1px !important;}
  }
```

I researched it at [media syntax possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762152/media-syntax-possible-combinations).  It seems to be valid code (judging by the post even though the [7.3 Recognized media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule) spec doesn't list the syntax the way the OP does).

Is it supposed to be positioned somewhere else in the .css or what?

Thanks

Comment: Here's some info [http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-aspect-ratio]. It appears the rule should be written as:  `@media screen and (min-device-aspect-ratio:0){ ... }`  Thing is, I don't know if "0" is a valid value.  The spec uses a ratio and I don't know what the coder meant by using "0".  "0" means nothing anyway---so the statement seems meaningless.


  [1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some info [www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-aspect-ratio](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-aspect-ratio).
It appears the rule should be written as
    `@media screen and (min-device-aspect-ratio:0){ ... }`
Thing is, I don't know if "0" is a valid value. The spec uses a ratio and I don't know what the coder meant by using "0". "0" means nothing anyway---so the statement seems meaningless.
 [www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries)

Answer (score 0):

Using the code:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
```

Is a way to target just webkit browsers as it matches a webkit browser with a minimum pixel ratio of zero which in affect is every webkit browser. The issue is that the webkit prefix won't validate against W3C standards as it's vendor specific - it should be used as a last resort and if you don't mind the CSS failing validation.